# SWEXX 5:1 sound card would it work with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, soundcard

I do use Ubuntu in the laptop but unfortunatelly very limited IT skills. Using Ubuntu was more a political decission than a practical one.

I need to buy an external 5:1 sound card and I cannot find a confirmation of any that would definitively work.

Does anybody know any or could advise me what to buy? Google seach was not very useful.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From the builder's site:

> **Q:** Will this card work in Linux?
>
> **A:** Yes this card is supported by Linux by using the "cmipci" driver. We only give support for Windows systems. Questions about Linux will not be answered.

The `cmipci` is already part of the kernel so your card should work out of the box. To give it a go download Ubuntu's LiveCD, boot from it and select the option to try Ubuntu. If you hear sound there then everything will be fine.